# TomEE + CXF configuration reference

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, cdi, openejb, apache-tomee

So I was trying to find any reference documentation or non-trivial examples for using the three.

The 'best' I found was:

- [TomEE/OpenEJB JAXRS refactoring](http://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tomeeopenejb-jaxrs-refactoring/)
- [Some tips for TomEE and
  JAXRS config](http://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/some-tips-for-tomee-and-jaxrs-config/)

The [TomEE Documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/documentation.html) doesn't list Jax-RS at all, and I was only able to find some examples consisting of a [single endpoint class](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-on-ejb/README.html)

Where can I find a comprehensive reference of configuration options?

**The main problem is that I'd know how to do most of the things I want when using standalone CXF, but I have hardly any idea how the JAX-RS integration in TomEE works.**

At the very least - I want some documentation-grade resource for the info contained in blog posts above.

Comment: Hi Jakub!  The TomEE JAX-RS distro does pass the JAX-RS TCK and is in pretty good shape.  As for documentation, I suspect best thing would be to focus on your specific questions/issues.  I'll follow up in your other questions.

Comment: I suspect this example is far too complicated, but does use JAX-RS and CDI and many other things  http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/polling-parent/README.html  Follow source links at the bottom for Github and Apache SVN references.

Comment: Thanks, but the example is still only a single Endpoint with rather simple setup - no @Provider, no properties (e.g. cxf.jaxrs.providers)

Comment: For specific questions see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445612/how-to-access-jaxrsserver-options-when-using-tomee-cxf-integration

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS isn't part of the base TomEE distribution because it isn't required in the web profile in Java EE 6, however, you can find it in the TomEE JAX-RS and TomEE Plus distributions (thanks David). It may not be with your specific implementations but take a look at http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/helloworld-rs/. Most of the quickstarts listed are built around the standard APIs and don't use anything proprietary so you should be able to get them to work on TomEE.

Comment: Maybe update the answer so that it says more specifically JAX-RS is part of the TomEE JAX-RS and TomEE Plus distributions.

Comment: I'm afraid checking out docs for other implementations will not help me much. Please see the edit to question

Answer (score 0):

There are several detailed examples here: http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/index.html

David added a detailed post here http://www.tomitribe.com/blog/2014/06/apache-tomee-jax-rs-and-arquillian-starter-project/

And more documented code examples here (look for modules beginning with rest): https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/trunk/examples

And finally the reference card here: http://tomee.apache.org/refcard/refcard.html