# CDI for JAX-RS providers in TomEE/OpenEJB

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, cdi, openejb, apache-tomee

I want to inject a dependency into a JAX-RS @Provider (say `MyExceptionMapper`) in OpenEJB/TomEE

My configuration goes like this:

interface:

```
 @Path("myPath") public interface MyEndpoint { /* .. */ }
```

implementation:

```
 @Stateless class EJBBackedMyEndpoint implements MyEndpoint { /* .. */ }
```

openejb-jar.xml

```
  <openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
    <ejb-deployment ejb-name="EJBBackedMyEndpoint">
        <properties>cxf.jaxrs.providers = exceptionMapper</properties>
    </ejb-deployment>
  </openejb-jar>
```

resources.xml

```
<resources> 
  <Service id="exceptionMapper" class-name="package.MyExceptionMapper"/>
</resources>
```

beans.xml present with just empty root element

How can I get CDI to work on this class? Is it even possible, or do I have to bridge it with JNDI lookup?

I have to admit I don't even know why I'm doing it in this particular way, as I was unable to find any serious documentation, as described in [TomEE + CXF configuration reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422126/tomee-openejb-jax-rs-configuration-reference)

Comment: which jax-rs implementation are you using? Is there any module that contains cdi integration?

Comment: I'm using the default CXF that is bundled with TomEE+ if there is any CDI integration I'd expect it to be already included

Comment: hm, not familiar with what's in there. Maybe David Blevins knows

Comment: CDI isn't supported in JAX-RS... yet. Look for JAX-RS 2.0 coming out soon which I *believe* does support it.

Comment: @exabrial was this lost in moderation since last year? Jax-rs 2.0 was released in May